# Spring Boot - Running one specific background job per pod

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

I'm coming from the PHP/Python/JS environment where it's a standard to run multiple instances of web application as separate processes and asynchronous tasks like queue processing as separate scripts.

**eg. in the k8s environment, there would be**

- N instances of **web server only**, each running in separate pod
- For each queue, **dynamic number of consumers, each in separate pod**
- **Cron scheduling using k8s crontab** functionality, leaving the scheduling process to k8s

Such approach matches well the cloud nature where the workload can be scheduled across both smaller number of powerful machines and **lot of less powerful machines** and allows very fine control of auto scaling (based on the number of messages in specific queue for example).

Also, there is a clear separation between the developer and DevOps responsibility.

Recently, I tried to replicate the same setup with **Java Spring Boot** application and failed miserably.

Even though Java frameworks say that they are "cloud native", it seems like all the documentation is still built around monolith application, which handles all consumers and cron scheduling in separate threads.

Clear answer to this problem is microservices but that's way out of scope.

**What I need is to deploy separate parts of application (like 1 queue listener only) per pod in the cloud yet keep the monolith code architecture.**

So, the question is:

How do I design my Spring Boot application so that:

- I can run the webserver separately without queue listeners and scheduled jobs
- I can run one queue listener per pod in the k8s
- I can use k8s cron scheduling instead of App level Spring scheduler?

I found several ways to achieve something like this but I expect there must be some "more or less standard way".

---

Alternative solutions that came to my mind:

- Having separate module with separate Application definition so that each "command" is built separately
- Using Spring Profiles to instantiate specific services only according to some environment variables
- Implement custom command line runner which would parse command name/queue name and dynamically create appropriate services (this seems to be the most similar approach to the way how it's done in "scripting languages")

What I mainly want to achieve with such setup is:

- To be able to run the application on lot of weak HW instead of having 1 machine with 32 cpu cores
- Easier scaling per workload
- Removing one layer from already complex monitoring infrastructure (k8s already allows very fine resource monitoring, application level task scheduling and parallelism makes this way more difficult)

Do I miss something or is it just that it's not standard to write Java server apps this way?
Thank you!

Comment: I have removed the `micronaut` tag as the question doesn't appear to involve  Micronaut.

Comment: 'What I need is to deploy separate parts of application (like 1 queue listener only) per pod in the cloud yet keep the monolith code architecture.' IMO difficult to achieve this with java/spring-boot. Best to break the application logically.

Comment: I agree @Smile opinion.

Answer (score 2):

> What I need is to deploy separate parts of application (like 1 queue listener only) per pod in the cloud yet keep the monolith code architecture.

I agree with [@jacky-neo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71598155/2446208) in terms of the appropriate architecture/best practice, but that may require you to break up your monolithic application.

To solve this without breaking up your monolithic application, deploy multiple instances of your monolith to Kubernetes each as a separate `Deployment`. Each deployment can have its own configuration. Then you can [utilize feature flags](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-feature-flags) and define the environment variables for each deployment based on the functionality you would like to enable.

In `application.properties`:

```
myapp.queue.listener.enabled=${QUEUE_LISTENER_ENABLED:false}
```

In your `Deployment` for the queue listener, enable the feature flag:

```yaml
env:
  - name: 'QUEUE_LISTENER_ENABLED'
    value: 'true'
```

You would then just need to configure your monolithic application to use this `myapp.queue.listener.enabled` property and only enable the queue listener when the property is set to `true`.

Similarly, you could also apply this logic to the Spring profile to only run certain features in your app based on the profile defined in your `ConfigMap`.

[This Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-feature-flags) explains the process I'm presenting here in detail.

For the scheduled task, just [set up a `CronJob` using a `curl` container](https://florianbuchner.com/kubernetes-curl-cronjob-for-internal-service/) which can invoke the service you want to perform the work.

### Edit

Another option based on your comments below -- split the shared logic out into a `shared` module (using Gradle or Maven), and have two other runnable modules like `web` and `listener` that depend on the `shared` module. This will allow you to keep your shared logic in the same repository, and keep you from having to build/maintain an extra library which you would like to avoid.

This would be a good step in the right direction, and it would lend well to breaking the app into smaller pieces later down the road.

[Here's some additional info](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) about multi-module Spring Boot projects using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Thanks, this is more in line with what I'm looking for. But on the Spring side, is there an easy way to control which beans gets created in which contexts? Or do I end up with loads of flags because Spring otherwise starts everything? Is there an easy way for a part of the app to only create what it "needs"? That whole thing is what I'm wondering.

Comment: Also, in my case it's not a "monolith", just code in a shared repo. So I'd like to use the databaseservice or whatever in both applications, without having to start having it as a separate library and import it, version it etc.

Comment: @Matsemann Regarding your first remark, there is no easy way to start only what it needs. It is possible, but not easy. As alternative, you could use feature-flags in combination with [excluded `AutoConfiguration` classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.auto-configuration.disabling-specific) ([via](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6749#issuecomment-242338043)) and settings like `spring.main.web-application-type=none`.

Comment: Could lazy beans be a way? For instance if I in my queue deployment only create a rabbitmq listener, will it then only create whatever other beans I use then, and not lots of other unrelated stuff?

Comment: @Matsemann have you considered just breaking up your project into modules (with Gradle or Maven)? You could just create multiple deployable modules (like a `jms` module, an `api`/`web` module, and a `shared` module, and deploy each one separately. Then you can keep all the code in the same codebase without needing to create any additional libraries.

Comment: @Matsemann about the lazy initialization, it could be useful depending on the use-case but I haven't used that enough to be able to speak definitively on it. But perhaps a combination of the feature flags + lazy initialization, or some default beans that do nothing when your feature flags are disabled, could both work.

Answer (score 1):

According to my expierence, I will resolve these issue as below. Hope it is what you want.

> I can run the webserver separately without queue listeners and
> scheduled jobs

Develop a [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) app to do it and deploy it as `service-A` in Kubernetes. In this app, you use `spring-mvc` to define the controller or REST controller to receive requests. Then use the Kubernetes `Nodeport` or define `ingress-gateway` to make the service accessible from outside the Kubernetes cluster. If you use session, you should save it into Redis or a similar shared place so that more instances of the service (pod) can share same session value.

> I can run one queue listener per pod in the k8s

Develop a new Spring Boot app to do it and deploy it as `service-B` in Kubernetes. This service only processes queue messages from [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or others, which can be sent from `service-A` or another source. In most times it should not be accessed from outside the Kubernetes cluster.

> I can use k8s cron scheduling instead of App level Spring scheduler?

In my opinion, I like to define a new Spring Boot app with `spring-scheduler` called `service-C` in Kubernetes. It will have only one instance and will not be scaled. Then, it will invoke `service-A` method at the scheduled time. It will not be accessible from outside the Kubernetes cluster. But if you like Kubernetes `CronJob`, you can just write a bash shell using `service-A`'s dns name in Kubernetes to access its REST endpoint.

The above three services can each be configured with different resources such as CPU and memory usage.

Comment: OP wants *'What I need is to deploy separate parts of application (like 1 queue listener only) per pod in the cloud yet keep the monolith code architecture.'*

Comment: I guess writer want to save some effort to re-contruct monolith code. He just seperate code as need. maybe processing queue is complicated and need more resource. so make it as micro-service is reasonable.

Comment: thx @blacktide, make my anwser to be readable. To deploy one monolithic code into different k8s pod, it is a good way to use a switch policy by config value.

Answer (score -3):

I do not get the essence of your post.
You want to have an application with "monolithic code architecture".
And then deploy it to several pods, but only parts of the application are actually running.
Why don't you separate the parts you want to be special to be applications in their own right?

Perhaps this is because I come from a Java background and haven't deployed monolithic scripting apps.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I expect it's the mindset shift.

How would you structure an application (or several applications) which shares the business logic so the code can't be easily separated into microservices but you want to have the flexibility during deployment?

What if I want to run webserver 3 times for Hight Availability and Fault Tolerance, next to it I need 30 instances of 1 queue consumer A + 1 instance of consumer B?

What If I do not have a machine powerful enough to run all of these as 1 application and instead have several less powerful machines?

Comment: Probably by making the 'business logic' piece into a lib, and then splitting the 'webserver' part, each 'consumer' piece, and the 'cron' piece into separate Spring apps. Alternatively, perhaps the 'business logic' piece should have its own Web API that 'webserver' and 'consumers' would call, with load balancing in between. Note that the resource overhead connected to spinning up a Spring app means you'll still want multi-threading at the application (pod) level, otherwise you want be using your resources effectively

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question.  It is asking another quesiton... "Why don't you separate the parts you want to be special to be applications in their own right?"